# Menu not visible in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, android-actionbar

I have a fragment that contains menu I have tried calling    `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in both `onCreate()` as well as `onCreateView()` and set a `toolbar` as my `Actionbar`. I have gone  through all the questions about the same here but none of the solutions seem to be working for me! I have tried changing the theme, menu.clear(), and returning true from `onCreateOptions()` of the Activity

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            }


            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                setHasOptionsMenu(true);

                // Inflating view layout

                layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.side_panel, container,false);
                toolbar = layout.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

                ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


                 return layout;
            }


            @Override
            public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
                super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_side_panel,menu);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            }
```

Comment: Can you try moving your toolbar to activity layout file and inflating it and setting it as action bar in Activity onCreate function. In fragment just try adding menu options.

Comment: No.... I have a search option in my menu

Answer (score 2):

If you have declared Toolbar in the XML file, Then try this 
First get a reference to Toolbar using findViewByid() then inflate your menu

```
 mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.main_menu);
```

Comment: While this method works in displaying my menu its is not useful for me as I am animating my search bar which doesnt work by using this

Comment: You animation doesn't work because you are probably setting the animated view to View.GONE in the beginning. Try setting it to View.INVISIBLE and see if the animation plays.